# Projecting data in R

Tags: r, function

Here my dataset, I have 194 countries with values from 2014 to 2018

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   iso3  time  y
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 AFG   2014     0.50
 2 AFG   2015     0.55
 3 AFG   2016     0.63
 4 AFG   2017     0.68
 5 AFG   2018     0.69
 6 AGO   2014     0.54
 7 AGO   2015     0.58
 8 AGO   2016     0.57
 9 AGO   2017     0.51
10 AGO   2018     0.61
```

What I would like to do is project data till 2023 using this function

```
proj <- function(y, time=2014:2018, target=2023){
  stopifnot(any(y>0) | any(y<1))
  period <- time[1]:target
  yhat <- predict(glm(y ~ time, family=quasibinomial), newdata=data.frame(time=period))
  return(data.frame(time=period, y=invlogit(yhat)))
}
```

Now the problem is that I don't know how to use functions..how to apply the abive function to my dataset to create a new dataset where I have both historical data from 2014 to 2018 and projected data till 2023 for all countries, in the same format as above.

Could you help?

Thank you very much

Comment: hmmmm the function you are showing, its a quasibinomial and the variables are not even in your data.frame.. what exactly is the question?

Comment: the variable is supposed to be value/100 in my data.frame. Does it make sense? Value is treatment coverage so between 0 and 100 - if we divide by 100 then values is between 0 and 1.I will edit the question.

Comment: Yes it would.. I can write an answer but yeah seems like it's something u need to understand more

Comment: thanks, that would be a good occasion to learn!

Comment: do you need to project for each country separately?

Comment: Yes, the new data set should have historical data from 2014 to 2018 and projected data from 2019 to 2023 for each country..I have 194 countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say this is your data:

```
df = structure(list(iso3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("AFG", "AGO"), class = "factor"), time = c(2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L
), y = c(0.5, 0.55, 0.63, 0.68, 0.69, 0.54, 0.58, 0.57, 0.51, 
0.61)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L))
```

You still need a inverse logit function, which should be:

```
invlogit =function (x){ 1/(1 + exp(-x)) }
```

Then what you need to provide, are the y data in the time period for each country, so for example:

```
subset(df,iso3=="AFG" & time %in% 2014:2018)
```

gives you a subset of the data.frame in country AFG from 2014 to 2018. This only works in your function if the data is complete  (goes from 2014 to 2018) and sorted. We try that:

```
proj(subset(df,iso3=="AFG" & time %in% 2014:2018)$y)

   time         y
1  2014 0.5057644
2  2015 0.5598027
3  2016 0.6124600
4  2017 0.6626145
5  2018 0.7093585
6  2019 0.7520495
7  2020 0.7903234
8  2021 0.8240714
9  2022 0.8533952
10 2023 0.8785516
```

I suggest writing a function that handles situations when data is not sorted or is missing:

```
func = function(data,country){
data = subset(data,iso3==country)
data[match(2014:2018,data$time),]$y
}

res = lapply(unique(df$iso3),function(i){
data.frame(country=i,proj(func(df,country=i)))
})

res = do.call(rbind,res)

    country time         y
1       AFG 2014 0.5057644
2       AFG 2015 0.5598027
3       AFG 2016 0.6124600
4       AFG 2017 0.6626145
5       AFG 2018 0.7093585
6       AFG 2019 0.7520495
7       AFG 2020 0.7903234
8       AFG 2021 0.8240714
9       AFG 2022 0.8533952
10      AFG 2023 0.8785516
11      AGO 2014 0.5479759
21      AGO 2015 0.5550113
31      AGO 2016 0.5620247
41      AGO 2017 0.5690134
51      AGO 2018 0.5759748
61      AGO 2019 0.5829061
71      AGO 2020 0.5898048
81      AGO 2021 0.5966684
91      AGO 2022 0.6034943
101     AGO 2023 0.6102802
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how to use this function. the complexity is that I need to do that for 194 countries so I guess I need to create a list of countries and do that in a loop? I am quite new to R.

Comment: yes you need to do that... ok i write this in my answer just once

Comment: please refrain from asking multiple questions or going beyond the scope of your question. you can read https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ to learn more about R

Comment: The question was on how to apply the function to the 194 countries, but ok I get your point! Thanks for the link! and thank you so much for resolving my issue.